# How to set border for wedges in matplotlib pie chart?

Tags: python, matplotlib, charts

Got some problem with plotting a pie chart in matplotlib. Currently it's plotting properly the chart itself, but there is a small issue with its wedges. As I set wedgeprops in arguments (eg. linewidth, same with linestyle) it change this for shadow that is beneath chart, not for wedges itself.

How to draw proper borders for wedges and not for shadows? This is how it looks like now.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

pie_chart_labels = ('Failed', 'Passed', 'Disabled')
pie_chart_colors = ('red', 'green', 'grey')
pie_chart_exploded = (0, 0.08, 0)
pie_chart_fig, pie_chart_ax = plt.subplots()
pie_chart_ax.margins(0.05)
pie_chart_ax.axis('equal')
pie_chart_test_results = (8, 5, 2)

pie_chart_ax.pie(pie_chart_test_results, 
                 explode=pie_chart_exploded, 
                 labels=pie_chart_labels,     
                 colors=pie_chart_colors, 
                 shadow=True, 
                 counterclock=False, 
                 startangle=90, 
                 wedgeprops={'linewidth': 1, 'linestyle': 'solid', 'antialiased': True})

pie_chart_fig.savefig('PieChart.png')
```

matplotlib border for shadow:

[image]

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The point is that your wedges currently do not have any edgeline which could be configured. If you give them an edge, you can also give it some properties.

```
wedgeprops={"edgecolor":"k",'linewidth': 5, 'linestyle': 'dashed', 'antialiased': True})
```

[image]

Comment: That's it! Thanks!